# Hyperlinking mutiple file types in content body

Tags: 7

I am designing a website, in which the content of body has several hyperlinks. Following is the sample body-

> This app is now available for android as well, which can be downloaded
>   from [Google Play](http://play.google.com/LinkDoesNotExist). [Here](http://www.example.com/screenshot1.jpg) you can see a screenshot of this app.
>   Some more description about this app goes here. Blah blah blah. A
>   [manual in PDF format](http://www.example.com/manual.pdf) has been attached to the website for getting
>   started into this app.

I am using [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) with [IMCE](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce) to upload all these files in server. I have manually created two sub-directories inside upload folder to keep my pdf and image files separate. Below is the screenshot of it-

[image]

While uploading pdf file, I select pdf sub-directory. However, inside IMCE profile configurations i.e. `admin/config/media/imce/profile/edit/1`, the directory path for upload has been given to parent directory. Below is the screenshot of it-

[image]

Now, when I try to access these sub-directories from browser, it displays error. Below is the screenshot of it-

[image]

Please help me to eliminate this error, also suggest a better way to handle multiple file type while using them as hyper linking.

Comment: What do you mean by "access these sub-directories"? How are you accessing them? The error seems very much unrelated to the linking of files in fields. How did you create those sub-directories and how do you select the sub-directory when uploading?

Comment: Did you remember to link one of the IMCE profiles to the role that you have? I frequently forget to do this: /admin/config/media/imce

Comment: @betherwisser: I created those directory manually i.e. using command line. Please see my updated question.

Comment: @AnneBonham: Just did it. I also keeps on forgetting it :D Thank you for reminding me. Please have a look in updated question. I am looking for better way to deal with multiple file types

Comment: What do you mean by "access these sub-directories from browser"?

Comment: @betherwisser: Added one more screenshot for better understanding. I should be clear now :) Please have a look in updated question.

Comment: Why are you trying to directly access that folder from the browser? Normally Drupal doesn't allow listings of directories like that.

Comment: It is just a security check. Even I don't need directory access. But the error msg should not reveal such information. Moreover, I am interested to learn about hypeinking mutiple file types in a content in a better way.